# Drupal overriding modules's function into another module's function duplicating the form

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am at beginner level of drupal trying to Overriding the third party `uc_cart_uc_cart_pane` function into my own custom function `custom_session_uc_cart_pane` but it is duplicating the form or result

Here is sample functions

```
/**
 * Implements hook_uc_cart_pane().
 */
function uc_cart_uc_cart_pane($items) {
  $body = array();

  if (!is_null($items)) {
    $body = drupal_get_form('uc_cart_view_form', $items) + array(
      '#prefix' => '<div id="cart-form-pane">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
  }

  $panes['cart_form'] = array(
    'title' => t('Default cart form'),
    'enabled' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 0,
    'body' => $body,
  );

  return $panes;
}

function custom_session_uc_cart_pane($items){
  $iframe = multi_domain_iframe();
  // echo "<pre>";
  // print_r($items);
  // exit;
  $pre_suf_fix = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div id="cart-form-pane1">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'.$iframe,
    );
  $body = array() + $pre_suf_fix;
  if (!is_null($items)) {
    $body = drupal_get_form('custom_session_view_form', $items) + $pre_suf_fix;
  }
  $panes['cart_form'] = array(
    'title' => t('Default cart form'),
    'enabled' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 0,
    'body' => $body,
  );

  return $panes;
}
```

any thing which i am missing.

Comment: If you want to modify existing form you have to look `hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change some thing specifically for a form you can use

[hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)

you do not need to override the function.

Thanks